# Does a standard user has write-access to create folder in c:\ drive so that user can create or write file inside it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista, uac

In Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP,
Does a standard user has write-access to create folder in c:\ drive so that user can create or write file inside it?

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7: Yes, the standard user can create a folder in C:\ and create file inside it.